# error: [Hilt] Null baseElement: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null baseElement

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, kapt, instrumented-test

I am trying to use Hilt to write some UI instrumented test.

I followed instructions given at developer site to setup Hilt for tests. But when i try running the test, i get following error -

```
Task :app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin FAILED
e: error: [Hilt]
  Null baseElement: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null baseElement
        at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.AutoValue_TestRootMetadata.<init>(AutoValue_TestRootMetadata.java:20)
        at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.TestRootMetadata.of(TestRootMetadata.java:75)
        at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.root.RootProcessor.processEach(RootProcessor.java:98)
        at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:195)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:188)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:985)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:901)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1227)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1340)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:231)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:194)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:115)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:301)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:292)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:172)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1623)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have setup a CustomTestRunner class -

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

override fun newApplication(
    cl: ClassLoader?,
    className: String?,
    context: Context?
): Application {
    return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
}
```

}

And replaced default testRunner with this class.

Then i setup my test as follows -

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(TestActivity::class.java)

    @get:Rule var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var testPropertiesManager: TestPropertiesManager


//UI test
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: Turns out the issue was due to gradle dependencies not downloading correctly. Maybe due to network, but i am not sure. So, as a workaround i had manually downloaded the jar/.aar files into libs folder in my project. Then i was getting this error. But afterwards, i removed the libs and tried downloading via gradle on another network. And it worked ;)